# How to use variables in hive load command

Tags: hadoop

I have multiple files to load into hive, like this

```
t47_corporation
t47_cp_deposit
t47_id_deposit
t47_individual
...
```

I try to load it using following command

```
for var in t47*; 
 do 
   hive -e "load data local inpath ${var} overwrite into table ${var}_tmp"; 
done
```

But I got an error

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:23 mismatched input 't47_id_deposit' expecting StringLiteral near 'inpath' in load statement

I am using hive 0.13

How should I finish this? Thanks

Comment: try `'${var}'` instead of `${var}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, thank u for inspiration

```
    for var in t47*;

    do 
      hive -e "load data local inpath \"${var}\" overwrite into table ${var}_tmp"; 

    done
```

this is executed successfully

Answer (score 0):

try this command:

for var in ${t*}; do hive -e "load data local inpath ${var} overwrite into table ${var}_tmp"; done